# Get a specific part of an array by daytime

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have an array with Youtube videos and I want a specific one by daytime.

```
Array
(

[10] => Array
    (
        [video_id] => 2
        [show_date] => 2014-11-01
        [show_time] => 14:40:00
        [video_duration] => 5470
        [video_youtube_id] => MTLObnglz_U
        [video_title] => Out Of Bounds (OV)
        [source] => channel:&nbsp;netzkino
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [video_id] => 155
        [show_date] => 2014-11-01
        [show_time] => 21:10:00
        [video_duration] => 9392
        [video_youtube_id] => OO-e8_-bMv8
        [video_title] => Foo Fighters Live at Lollapalooza Brazil 2012 Full Concert HD 720p
        [source] => 
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [video_id] => 3
        [show_date] => 2014-11-01
        [show_time] => 23:59:00
        [video_duration] => 5520
        [video_youtube_id] => cf7Eu9WJ_ek
        [video_title] => City of Sex (KomÃ¶die mit Nicole Kidman)
        [source] => 
    )
```

)

So when its between "2014-11-01 21:10:00" and (+video_duration) "2014-11-01 23:46:31" I want to get the "Foo Fighters":

```
[11] => Array
    (
        [video_id] => 155
        [show_date] => 2014-11-01
        [show_time] => 21:10:00
        [video_duration] => 9392
        [video_youtube_id] => OO-e8_-bMv8
        [video_title] => Foo Fighters Live at Lollapalooza Brazil 2012 Full Concert HD 720p
        [source] => 
    )
```

Comment: Did you try just looping through them and checking the date? Show what you've done... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast answer, but I´m realy a beginner (noob)... I have no idea how I can get the right result... How can I loop this array to get my result? 

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use foreach() on array and check each record. Something like this:

```
$array = array(...); // Your array
$newArray = array();
$currentTime = time();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    $fromTime = strtotime($value['show_date'] . ' ' . $value['show_time']);
    $toTime = $fromTime + $value['video_duration'];

    if ($fromTime <= $currentTime && $toTime >= $currentTime) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your great answer it works perfect.. :)
one last (stupid) question... is it possible to get the next video (City of S**) too? Thank you again :)

Comment: You can make it in many ways. Try after $newArray[] = $value; this code: $next = next($array);